# How to plot multiple subplot dataframe histograms in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot four dataframe column histograms in 4 subplots as follows:

```
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
ax2[0, 0] = completeDF['Number_of_Weeks_Used'].plot.hist(bins=100, alpha=0.8)
ax2[0, 1] = completeDF['Season'].plot.hist(bins=100, alpha=0.8)
```

But it is merging both plots in 1 subplot as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `axes` are being specified in an incorrect manner

```py
import pandas_datareader as web  # not part of pandas; conda or pip install
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot

# get test data
df = web.DataReader('^gspc', data_source='yahoo', start='2020-09-01', end='2020-09-28').iloc[:, :4]

# set figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(8, 8))

# plot to different axes
df.High.plot.hist(bins=100, alpha=0.8, ax=ax[0, 0])
df.Low.plot.hist(bins=100, alpha=0.8, ax=ax[0, 1])
df.Open.plot.hist(bins=100, alpha=0.8, ax=ax[1, 0])
df.Close.plot.hist(bins=100, alpha=0.8, ax=ax[1, 1])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

- The following, will also work

```py
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(8, 8))

df.High.plot.hist(bins=100, alpha=0.8, ax=ax1, label='High')
df.Low.plot.hist(bins=100, alpha=0.8, ax=ax2, label='Low')
df.Open.plot.hist(bins=100, alpha=0.8, ax=ax3, label='Open')
df.Close.plot.hist(bins=100, alpha=0.8, ax=ax4, label='Close')
```